# Define outliers in correlation with right-skewed data (log-log plot)

Tags: correlation, outliers, threshold

I have a dataset of counts of occurrences of variables in different classes. For each class, I have an equivalent control created by shuffling the dataset.
For instance, this could be words from documents and class of the document (magazine article vs textbook vs social media post). For each document, I have counted how many times each word appears.
The controls have been created by randomly assigning labels to the document and counting again how many times each word appears.

I am interested in finding which words appear in a class more often than you would expect by chance. Because each document will have a different amount of words, instead of looking at counts, I am looking at the proportion of the total each word makes up in the control and in the data (i.e. if "and" appears 30 times and "then" appears 3 in 300 words, they will be 0.1 and 0.01 respectively). Most of these words actually make up a very small proportion of the text, whilst a few have much larger occurrences.

I have now plotted this on a log-log graph. Here, each dot is a word and I have real data on the x-axis and control on the y-axis. The graph is coloured by density, yellow in the denser areas.
As expected, I see quite strong correlation, but some outliers. I currently use a 3-fold change to select the words I am interested in, but this includes a lot of the points in the lower-left corner. Is there a mathematical way of setting a better threshold I could use? I think the more interesting points for me are the ones I circled in blue.

[image]

Comment: You will get a better picture by using square root scales.  That will make the outliers simpler to characterize and identify.